# Backbone - preserve thead in a table View

Tags: backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js for my project.
Sorry, I am a Backbone newbie, therefore I may be missing something very trivial.

This is an HTML snippet:

```
<table id="notes" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>title</th><th>comment</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="notesTableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the Backbone code that it is supposed to "inject" HTML in that snippet:

```
App.view.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el:"tbody#notesTableBody",

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (note) {
            $(this.el).append(new App.view.NoteListItemView({model:note}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});
```

For clarity, I haven't pasted the `NoteListItemView` code because I don't think it is relevant.

My problem is that the HTML code rendered by Backbone is as follows:

```
<table id="notes" class="table">
    <tbody id="notesTableBody">
    <tr><td>title 1</td><td>comment 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically Backbone removed the thead from the table.
I don't understand why - how can I make sure Backbone doesn't remove it?

Comment: I don't think Backbone is doing anything to the `<thead>` (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cFvX2/), how are you creating and rendering that view? `$('#notes').html((new App.view.NoteListView).render().el)`?

Comment: Hi "mu is too short". That's exactly the problem - well done! I indeed render it as you showed. The problem now is that I don't know how to change that line to preserve the thead. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `NoteListView` won't write anything outside of its `el` (for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cFvX2/) so your problem is elsewhere.

My guess was that you were doing something equivalent to this:

```
var v = new App.view.NoteListView;
$('#notes').html(view.render().el);
```

and that will completely replace the content of the `#notes` table with just the `<tbody>` (i.e. `NoteListView`'s `el`).

There are couple ways around your problem. You could just call `render` and ignore what it returns:

```
var v = new App.view.NoteListView;
v.render();
```

That's pretty much what my first demo fiddle did.

Or you could use [`id` and `tagName` instead of `el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

```
App.view.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'notesTableBody',
    tagName: 'tbody',
    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (note) {
            $(this.el).append(new App.view.NoteListItemView({model:note}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

and then [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the view's `el` to `$('#notes')`:

```
var v = new App.view.NoteListView;
$('#notes').append(v.render().el);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HTAkM/

You could also let the caller specify the `el`:

```
App.view.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (note) {
            $(this.el).append(new App.view.NoteListItemView({model:note}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

and then `render` into `el` without caring about `render`'s return value:

```
var v = new App.view.NoteListView({ el: $('#notesTableBody') });
v.render();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2Ptkp/

---

And while I'm here, you don't need to `$(this.el)` anymore, recent versions of Backbone provide [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) for your views:

> **$el** `view.$el`
>
> A cached jQuery (or Zepto) object for the view's element. A handy reference instead of re-wrapping the DOM element all the time.

If your view is wrapping a collection, you should use `this.collection` instead of `this.model`:

```
new SomeView({ collection: some_collection })
```

Views treat the [`collection` option specially just like `model`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...] There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

Backbone collections also have [several Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you don't need to say this:

```
_.each(some_collection.models, function(m) { ... });
```

you can call `each` right on the collection:

```
some_collection.each(function(m) { ... });
```

Also, if you're binding to a `"reset"` event:

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
```

you probably want your `render` to clear out the `el` before appending more things to it:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    this.collection.each(function(note) { ... });
}
```

If you don't [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) the `el` you'll be adding more things to it when you probably mean to replace its contents with new things.